NGINX Configuration for Laravel Subdirectory Serving PHP and Static Files Correctly
I have 2 Laravel sites;
My main site and my wedding site
I deployed my wedding site in the same server. My wedding site is in a diff repo than my main site. Below is my nginx config
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.bunlongheng.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bunlongheng.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/bunlongheng.com.key;

    root /home/bheng/wedding/public;
    index index.html index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location ^~ /wedding {
        index index.html index.php;
        alias /home/bheng/wedding/public;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        try_files $uri $uri/ @wedding;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location @wedding {
        rewrite ^/wedding/(.*)$ /wedding/index.php?$1 last;
    }
}

My wedding seems to have issues loading the assets from my wedding repo:
https://www.bunlongheng.com/wedding/

My wedding project loaded perfectly on my local

Can someone please help me with the correct configuration to make my wedding site load assets properly?
